# P2P video streaming from device to device using WebRTC?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, p2p

I'm trying to find a library/collection of libraries capable of p2p video streaming between devices.

By devices I mean:

- embedded C++ device to Android Phone/Tablet
- embedded C++ device to IOS phone/Table
- embedded C++ device to any modern browsers
- embedded C++ device to another embedded C++ device

In this case the **C++ running device** will be the sole **broadcaster** while other devices types can be **only receivers**.

From what I've researched I might be able to use **WebRTC** and the native clients to achieve all the above, however I have no experience with **WebRTC** and I need to know if the above are possible?

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @jurgemaister is it? is this not a general and valid programming question? it does not involve code but it involves a valid answer to an assumption I have

Comment: If you read the link in my previous comment, you would have seen "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam".

Comment: @jurgemaister If you read the question I already have the library/link/tool/software, I want a validation to my assumption, not asking for anyone to solve the problem for me, not creating opinionated answers, I just want to know If my assumption is valid or if I'm on a wrong track, regards

Comment: Well, "what WebRTC libraries could help me achieve this?" sounds like a request for a library to me. The answer to your other question, whether this is possible, is yes.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, but as jurgemaister points out, the Stack Overflow community has opted against allowing them for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: @Pekka웃  removed any reference that might be opinion based

Comment: @jurgemaister  removed any reference that might be opinion based